# Removing Facebook contact field from user contact not working

Tags: functions, customization, contact

I'm trying to unset the Facebook link for users who registered in the past 365 days. For users who have completed more than a year, don't unset.

Here's my code which is not working:

```
function modify_user_contact_methods( $user_contact ) {

    get_currentuserinfo(); 
        $user_data = get_userdata($user_ID);
        $registered_date = $user_data->user_registered;
        if (strtotime($registered_date) > strtotime('-365 days')){
             // Remove user contact methods
         unset( $user_contact['facebook']    );
        }

    return $user_contact;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'modify_user_contact_methods' );
```

It shows the field. If I remove the condition, it unsets for every user. So the set/unset is correct, only the 365 condition is wrong, I guess. But it seems correct, what amI doing wrong? Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs things first... [always, always enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG). Secondly, you should accept the `$user` parameter in your callback - otherwise you are always checking the *logged in user*, not the user within the current context:

```
function modify_user_contact_methods( $methods, $user ) {
    if ( ! $user instanceof WP_User ) {
        if ( ! $user = wp_get_current_user() )
            return $methods;
    }

    if ( strtotime( $user->user_registered ) > strtotime( '1 year ago' ) ) {
         unset( $methods['facebook'] );
    }

    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'modify_user_contact_methods', 10, 2 );
```